# QT Dialog box when building is cutting off my UI content, how do I resize the dialog box so this does not happen?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

[image]

Here is the example of what is happening. Above is the simple design of my UI, but below when I build my project, everything within is getting cut. What is the issue? I can't seem to find it despite trying to resize a bunch of my widgets.

[image]

This is what my QT dialog box structure looks like right now.
Then in my main.cpp file I just had

```
w.setFixedSize(560,180);
w.setWindowTitle("Servo Control");
```

Comment: Does the outer "Servo Control" widget not have a layout?

Comment: FYI: [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) and [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html)

Comment: I updated my post with what the layout is right now. I am a qt noob, so everything has a layout but I am not sure about servo control because that I defined in the main file, so that is confusing to me. The overlap between using their UI to make it vs defining it in the code.

Let me know if what I added above is helpful. Thanks for documentation, I will check that in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Update: I applied a grid layout to the outermost hierarchy and this fixed my problem. Strange though because the video I was following did not have any layout on it, but did not run into the same problem.

Comment: `QLayout` (and derived) is _the_ basic tool to arrange widgets and makes them responsive to size changes which may be influenced even from config. beyond the application. If the video didn't mention this... Maybe, the video is not that valuable as you expected. (I must admit I myself prefer written material. Qt comes with one of the best online documentations I've ever seen - a variety of basic examples included. Due to its popularity, there is much of additional info available in the Web, mostly in the Qt forum as well as in Stack Overflow.)